# Select immediate predecessor by date

Tags: drools

I am new to Drools and I'm using Drools 7.12.0 to try and validate a set of meter readings, which look like

```
public class MeterReading() {
    private long id;
    private LocalDate readDate;
    private int value;
    private String meterId
    private boolean valid;

/* Getters & Setters omitted */

}
```

As part of the validation I need to compare the values of each MeterReading with its immediate predecessor by readDate.

I first tried using 'accumulate'

```
when $mr: MeterReading()
  $previousDate: LocalDate() from accumulate(MeterReading($pdate: readDate < $mr.readDate ), max($pdate))

then
  System.out.println($mr.getId() + ":" + $previousDate);
end
```

but then discovered that this only returns the date of the previous meter read, not the object that contains it. I then tried a custom accumulate with

```
when
$mr: MeterReading()

$previous: MeterReading() from accumulate(
      $p: MeterReading(id != $mr.id),
      init( MeterReading prev = null; ),

      action( if( prev == null ||  $p.readDate < prev.readDate) {
         prev = $p;
      }),
      result(prev))
 then
  System.out.println($mr.getId() + ":" + $previous.getId() + ":" + $previous.getReadDate());

 end
```

but this selects the earliest read in the set of meter readings, not the immediate predecessor. Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I should be doing or reading to be able to select the immediate predecessor to each individual meter read.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

After further research I found this article http://planet.jboss.org/post/how_to_implement_accumulate_functions which I used to write my own accumulate function;\

```
public class PreviousReadFinder  implements AccumulateFunction {
@Override

public Serializable createContext() {
  return new PreviousReadFinderContext();
}

@Override
public void init(Serializable context) throws Exception {
  PreviousReadFinderContext prfc = (PreviousReadFinderContext) context;
  prfc.list.clear();
}

@Override
public void accumulate(Serializable context, Object value) {
  PreviousReadFinderContext prfc = (PreviousReadFinderContext) context;
  prfc.list.add((MeterReading) value);
}

@Override
public void reverse(Serializable context, Object value) throws Exception {
  PreviousReadFinderContext prfc = (PreviousReadFinderContext) context;
  prfc.list.remove((MeterReading) value);
}

@Override
public Object getResult(Serializable context) throws Exception {
  PreviousReadFinderContext prfc = (PreviousReadFinderContext) context;
  return prfc.findLatestReadDate();
}

@Override
public boolean supportsReverse() {
  return true;
}

@Override
public Class<?> getResultType() {
  return MeterReading.class;
}

@Override
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {

}

@Override
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException,  ClassNotFoundException {

}

private static class PreviousReadFinderContext implements Serializable {
    List<MeterReading> list = new ArrayList<>();

public Object findLatestReadDate() {

Optional<MeterReading> optional =  list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(MeterReading::getReadDate));
if (optional.isPresent()) {
  MeterReading to = optional.get();
  return to;
}
  return  null;
}
 }
}
```

and my rule is now

```
rule "Opening Read With Previous"

  dialect "mvel"

  when $mr: MeterReading()
       $pmr: MeterReading() from accumulate($p: MeterReading(readDate < $mr.readDate ), previousReading($p))

then
  System.out.println($mr.getId() + ":" + $pmr.getMeterReadDate());
end
```

How do I write a rule to select the eatliest meter reading in the set which does not have a previous read?